# Better understand a function expanding aliases in `zsh`

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to understand how this `zsh` widget works:

```
expand-aliases() {
  unset 'functions[_expand-aliases]'
  functions[_expand-aliases]=$BUFFER
  (($+functions[_expand-aliases])) &&
    BUFFER=${functions[_expand-aliases]#$'\t'} &&
    CURSOR=$#BUFFER
}

zle -N expand-aliases
bindkey '\e^E' expand-aliases
```

I found the code in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150737/232487). Its purpose is to expand all the aliases on the command line when you hit `C-M-e`.

It works but there are several things I don't understand in the code.

Here's what I think I understand and what I don't understand:

```
zle -N expand-aliases
```

This line installs a widget called `expand-aliases` which will invoke the function with the same name.

```
bindkey '\e^E' expand-aliases
```

This line binds the widget to the key chord `C-M-e`.

```
unset 'functions[_expand-aliases]'
```

I don't understand this line, because I don't know how the array `functions` was populated.

```
functions[_expand-aliases]=$BUFFER
```

This line stores inside the associative array `functions` the contents of the current command line, with the key `_expand-aliases`.

```
(($+functions[_expand-aliases])) &&
```

To better understand how this line works, I've executed the following commands:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias -g V='|vipe'
functions[_expand-aliases]='ls V'
echo $functions[_expand-aliases]           →  ls --color=auto | vipe
echo $+functions[_expand-aliases]          →  1
(($+functions[_expand-aliases])); echo $?  →  0
```

I'm not sure, but from these results, I think that `$functions[_expand-aliases]` somehow expands the aliases in the current command line, and that `$+functions[_expand-aliases]` returns a boolean flag which checks whether the command line is syntactically valid.

However, I don't understand the `$+` token. I searched for it in all the `zsh` man pages, but couldn't find it.

```
BUFFER=${functions[_expand-aliases]#$'\t'} &&
```

This line probably redefines the contents of the command line, with its expansion.

```
CURSOR=$#BUFFER
```

This line positions the cursor at the end of the command.

---

Could someone better explain how this code works? Or at least quote the sections in the `zsh` man pages where the `$+` token and the `functions` array are described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$+functions[_expand-aliases]` is 1 if the associative array `functions` contains the key `_expand-aliases` and 0 otherwise. This is described in the [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) as `${+name}`. Under the entry for `${name}`, the manual explains that the braces are optional. I don't think the manual states explicitly that you can use an [array name with a subscript](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts) instead of a name. The zsh manual is not an easy read.

The `functions` array is a “magic” associative array that is tied to function definitions. Defining a function adds an element to this array where the key is the function name and the value is the function body, normalized. Conversely, adding an element to the array defines a function with the given name and body.

```
unset 'functions[_expand-aliases]'               # unset any previous function
functions[_expand-aliases]=$BUFFER               # define a function whose body is the content of the command line
(($+functions[_expand-aliases])) &&              # if the command line is a syntactically correct function body, then …
BUFFER=${functions[_expand-aliases]#$'\t'} &&    # set the command line to the normalized function definition
CURSOR=$#BUFFER                                  # move the cursor to the end of the command line
```

If `functions` was an ordinary array then this wouldn't change the value of `BUFFER` (except for stripping a leading tab) and the test on the third line would always be true. But because of the “magic” nature of `functions`, what you get out of it is not what you put in, it's a normalized version — in particular, with aliases expanded. The test on the third line fails if the function definition is not syntactically correct.